# VB.net How to Update 2 column in a single sql code

Tags: sql

I want to update status and confirmstudentID to the room table at the same time, can I do in single sql code or should I split it out? How?

```
       sql = "update room set status = '" & status & "' and set confirmstudentid= " & Form1.stuID & "where id=" & lblroomID.Text & ";"
```

Comment: Please use [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/542510/87698). Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below;

```
sql = "update room set status = '" & status & "' , confirmstudentid = " & 
       Form1.stuID & " where id= " & lblroomID.Text & ";"
```

You only need to separate the columns by a comma `,` instead of adding another `set`